# byte[] upload to mysql blob contains no data

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, image, uwp

I'm trying to upload a byte array to a mysql column type mediumblob. after the upload I see the blob has a size in kilobytes, however, when I download the file and view it in notepad... it's just empty white space.

here's how I am getting my bytes from an image PNG file:

```
private async void artworkFileBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        artworkfile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (artworkfile != null)
        {
            artworkSet = true;
            //var stream = await musicfile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            artworkFileBTN.Content = artworkfile.DisplayName;
            var stream = await artworkfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var streamBytes = await artworkfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            var bytes = new byte[(int)streamBytes.Length];
            ArtworkRawData =bytes;

        }
        else
        {
            //  
        }
    }
```

can anyone tell me why my array contains only whitespace?

Comment: something in this area I'm guessing... I'm setting a length, but how do I set the content?

            var streamBytes = await artworkfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            var bytes = new byte[(int)streamBytes.Length];
            ArtworkRawData =bytes;

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
 byte[] result;
            using (Stream streambytes = await artworkfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {

                    streambytes.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    result = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }


            ArtworkRawData = result;
```